# How long will IE compatibility modes work?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, backwards-compatibility, compatibility-mode

Unfortunately, we have a massive legacy web application at work that we can't get rid of. It works on IE only, and is completely dependent on the "X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE8" to work correctly in newer IE versions.

My question is whether this is likely to one day suddenly stop working. I.e., will IE12 (or 13 or 14) come out one day and render the site useless because it doesn't bother with compatibility mode anymore?

If so, management won't want to hear it, but the sooner they do, the better.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Microsoft is the only resource that can answer questions about future plans for IE (which clearly now as of 2021 do not exist). We cannot answer questions about any plans for an off-site vendor, service or site. Contact that vendor, service or site directly for information related to their future plans.

Answer (score 4):

As of IE11, document modes are deprecated but continue to work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I don't think they've decided (as of Jan 2014) exactly when it will be removed entirely (all at once in IE12 or gradually). Probably it depends on the amount of resistance people give to the deprecation status.

I also maintain a big internal application built between 2000-2004 or so. We have been banging the drum of needing to redo parts of the old site for years but new features are always priority. Personally I am bracing for hitting a brick wall with IE12 later this year, but hoping there will be a gradual removal.

---

Edit: in early 2015 I've been reading that Windows 10 will ship with 2 browsers: code-name Spartan for the latest/greatest, and IE for legacy support. It's worth googling "Windows Edge" (formerly "Windows 10 Spartan") if you're interested in this topic. Possibly this is their answer for how to continue supporting older internal corporate web apps, without compromising the main consumer browser.

Hopefully the legacy browser doesn't fall behind the newer support, since our internal app is a mix of new and old web pages. It would suck if our company couldn't use the latest web technologies of 2016, 2017, etc., because older pages force our users to use the legacy browser. :(

Answer (score 4):

Editor's Note: Microsoft has since announced that the official name for their new browser is "Microsoft Edge". Substitute it for any instance of [Project] Spartan that you see.

> Powered by a new rendering engine, Spartan is designed for interoperability with the modern web. We’ve deliberately moved away from the versioned document modes historically used in Internet Explorer, and now use the same markup as other modern browsers. Spartan’s new rendering engine is designed to work with the way the web is written today.

The [IE Dev Channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn725043) has a build you can use to test the new defaults. Here are the prerequisites:

- Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 SP1
- Internet Explorer 11
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 (full version)
- PowerShell 3 (x86 or x64)

Here is the official recommendation:

> Starting with IE11, document modes are considered deprecated and should no longer be used. Webpages that require legacy document modes to display properly should be rewritten to use features defined by modern standards. To learn more, see Compatibility changes in IE11.

**References**

- [Project Spartan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/01/22/project-spartan-and-the-windows-10-january-preview-build.aspx)
- [Compatibility changes in IE11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625)
- [Building a more Interoperable Web with Microsoft Edge](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/06/17/building-a-more-interoperable-web-with-microsoft-edge/)
- [Internet Explorer Developer Channel FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn725043)
- [Announcing Internet Explorer Developer Channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/06/16/announcing-internet-explorer-developer-channel.aspx)
- [Internet Explorer Developer Channel for Windows 7 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43360)
- [Internet Explorer Developer Channel for Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43359)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your concern.. that is probably why they introduced Enterprise mode, which works great for Internal company applications, but it has to be set at the enterprise level, and cant be set for public facing websites like the ua compatible meta tag.

I also asked the same question to Microsoft, and they have not given me a definite date, but they said in the (**very near future**), forcing a deprecated document mode will not work.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 24 2015, Speaking about Windows 10 operating system, Microsoft has come up with entirely new browser called Microsoft Edge (formerly Project Spartan). Edge will be using a new rendering engine contained in EdgeHTML.dll and this will NOT have any compatibility mode. However, for legacy applications, Microsoft have also included IE 11 (based on MSHTML.dll) in Windows 10 operation system and this version of IE 11 WILL support compatibility mode.

That said, I think as far as Windows 10 is there, you can use IE 11 Compatibility mode. However, going forward, Microsoft will not invest in IE 11 and will continue to upgrade Microsoft Edge.

References:
[updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/03/24/updates-from-the-project-spartan-developer-workshop.aspx)